# Any convention for "given an empty list return an empty list" when matching patterns?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, convention

When pattern matching a list, it seems common to return an empty list when given an empty list. We can match an empty list to `Nil` or `List()`, but we can return empty as `Nil`, `List()` or by returning the given list argument itself.

What's the convention here?
When would you choose one method over another?

Examples:

```
def givenEmptyNumsReturnsNil(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
    case List() => Nil
    case x :: xs => ???
}

def givenEmptyNumsReturnsEmptyList(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
    case List() => List()
    case x :: xs => ???
}

def givenEmptyNumsReturnsNums(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
    case List() => nums
    case x :: xs => ???
}
```

Comment: I would always do: `case Nil => Nil`. `List()` calls `List.apply()` which calls `Array().toList` if I'm not mistaken. It's just not needed. `Nil` is an `object` and you always have that same instance. It's also clear what you mean.

Comment: In Lecture 5.1 of Martin Odersky's Coursera course, for the implementation of reverse (around 10:00) he writes it to return the given arg, then changes to return List(). This makes the choice seem completely arbitrary.

Comment: Well, the difference in performance is negligible. I prefer `Nil` because it is designed to be the empty `List`. It is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm scala beginner and don't know any existing convention about it. My things about it:

- The last one isn't intuitive
- I prefer return that I match. If I have case List(), so I return List().
- You can also match Nil:

-

```
def givenEmptyNumsReturnsNil(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xs => ???
}
```

But Nil and List() are the same.

Answer (score 1):

For choice better way, just clarify what inside:

case **N1**:

```
def givenEmptyNumsReturnsEmptyList(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
  case List() => List()
  case x :: xs => ???
}
```

Will call `unaplay` method from object `List`, after will call `apply` method of object `List`.

case **N2**:

```
def givenEmptyNumsReturnsNil(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xs => ???
}
```

Will compare value before match with object `Nil` and will return object `Nil`

And in case of choice I prefer case **N2** because it is little bit optimal.